# Как вернуть null через Type.GetValue(object)

Tags: c#

В общем, у меня есть метод, который сериализует объект какого то класса и возвращает json-строку. Но при попытке взять свойство, значение которого равняется null, мой метод не пишет ничего. Ниже сам код:

```
public string Serialize(object obj)
{
    List<string> props = new List<string>();
    Type type = obj.GetType();
    
    foreach (PropertyInfo elem in type.GetProperties())
    {
        string currentPropertyFormat = $"\u0022{elem.Name}\u0022:{elem.GetValue(obj)}";
        props.Add(currentPropertyFormat);
    }
    
    string jsonString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
    {
        jsonString += props[i];
        if (i != props.Count - 1)
            jsonString += ",";
    }
    
    return "{" + jsonString + "}";
}
```

Comment: `elem.GetValue(obj, null)` попробуй

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6916242 может быть полезно

Comment: @Frehzy интерполяция `null` возвращает `""`, здесь проблема именно в этом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Text.Json;
```

```
JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
```

Велосипед уже изобретен, можно сразу ехать.

А так починить достаточно просто

```
elem.GetValue(obj) ?? "null"
```

---

Как взять в кавычки, если строка

```
object value = elem.GetValue(obj);
string textValue = value is string text ? $"\"{text.Replace("\"", "\\\"")}\"" : $"{value ?? "null"}";
string currentPropertyFormat = $"\"{elem.Name}\":{textValue}";
```

Вы только не учли, а что если этот `value` - класс или массив? Тогда его надо будет сериализовать соответственно как `{...}` или `[...]`. То есть я подозреваю, что нужен рекурсивный алгоритм, либо конечный автомат.

Comment: Это вузовская домашка. Реализовать собственную сериализацию

Comment: И кстати, может знаете, как в интерполяционной строке выводить строку в кавычках, если elem.GetType == string?

Comment: @ValentinBazdukov дополнил ответ